# Error in Android Manifest - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android development. I was trying to develop an android application in Eclipse Indigo. I want to open a new screen when the user clicks a button. So I added a new activity, and suddenly after adding the new activity, this error appeared. I saw similar questions here, and what I understood was, the XML file should not contain more than one manifest tag and application tag. My file contains neither and I don't understand what happened. Please help me..

Here is my Android Manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.e.dropdown"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.e.dropdown.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
     android:name="com.e.dropdown.ClickActivity"
     class=".ClickActivity" 
     android:label="@string/screen2">
  </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please mention the error you are getting ?

Comment: what do you expect class=".ClickActivity" to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**class=".ClickActivity"**

Remove above line from below code

```
<activity
 android:name="com.e.dropdown.ClickActivity"
 class=".ClickActivity" 
 android:label="@string/screen2">
```

Comment: Hey thank u so much..for ur help.. The error disappeared.. What was the problem?

Comment: You have already defined "android:name" which will refer to your class ClickActivity and there is not attribute like "class"

Comment: @AparnaShajiPeter please vote and accept the answer if you found helpful.

Answer (score 4):

remove `class=".ClickActivity"` you dont need that in order to start new activity

Comment: Hey thank u so much..! I removed that line and the error disappeared. Can u explain me what the problem was?

Comment: well "class" doesn't exists like a attribute in androidmanifest. By android:name attribute you are defining the class, so thats all you have to use.